# Mysql - 2 tables sort by date_posted

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, unions

I have 2 tables in my sql

Instagram

- id
- url
  -caption
- image
- date_posted

Twitter

- screen_name
- text
- date_posted

The data posted is a unix timestamp. What is the best approach for retrieving and ordering by data_posted?

I think I have a few options

- one table with some blank fields (screen_name is a twitter only field for example)
- a table to create a join.
- retrieve them both into an array are try and sort there.

Any ideas on the best approach would be appreciated.

Comment: Provide some sample data and your expected result.

Comment: A simple union with some dummy columns (both queries in the union must have the same number/types of columns). Use that as the FROM of a select and sort on date_posted.

Comment: Hi Sloan, yes that's what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT id, url_caption, image, '' as screen_name,'' as text,date_posted FROM instagram 
    UNION
    SELECT 0 as id, '' as url_caption, '' as image, screen_name,text, date_posted FROM twitter)
ORDER BY date_posted
```